# How to prove $\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}dx<\frac{\pi^{3}}{144}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives, inequality

> Prove that:
>   $$\frac{\pi}{2}-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}dx<\frac{\pi^{3}}{144}$$

I tried to find minimum value of the integral so that origin formula < $\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\min{f})<\frac{\pi^{3}}{144}$. Since I failed, I think my method is totally wrong. Would you tell me how to slove it? Best regards!

Comment: do you mean $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes. I typed it $\text{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sin x\geq x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}$ then
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx\geq \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1-\dfrac{x^2}{6} dx=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi^3}{144}$$

Answer (score 3):

Easy to show that
$$\sin{x}-x+\frac{x^3}{6}\geq0$$
for all $x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and use that an integral of non-negative function is non-negative.

Indeed, let $f(x)=\sin{x}-x+\frac{x^3}{6}$.

Thus, $$f'(x)=\cos{x}-1+\frac{x^2}{2},$$
$$f''(x)=-\sin{x}+x\geq0.$$

Thus, $f'(x)\geq f'(0)=0$ and $f(x)\geq f(0)=0$.

Id est,
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{f(x)}{x}dx\geq0$$ or
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{x}-1+\frac{x^2}{6}\right)dx\geq0$$ or  $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}dx+\left(-x+\frac{x^3}{18}\right)_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\geq0,$$

which gives the needed inequality.

Comment: The inequality for $\sin x$ is valid for all $x \ge 0$ of course

Comment: @orangeskid We have $0<x\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: Yes indeed. However, for the sake of record, the inequality is valid on $[0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$f(x) = x-\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin t} {t} \, dt - \frac{x^{3}}{18}$$ so that $$f'(x) =1-\frac{\sin x} {x} - \frac{x^{2}}{6}=\frac{1}{x}\left(x-\frac{x^{3}}{6}-\sin x\right)$$ By Taylor's theorem the expression in parentheses is negative for $x>0$ and hence $f'(x) <0$ for all $x>0$. Therefore $f(\pi/2)<f(0)=0$ and we are done.